# CoffeeScript get select field from id/class/name

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm new at CoffeeScript and getting stuck on some stupid task. I can't get a selector field from his id nor custom class nor name.

**users/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for user do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, 'erro') %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <p>Pseudo:</p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, id:'name_field' %>

    <%= f.label :status %>
    <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(%w(Visitor Member), id: 'status_select', selected: user.status) %>

    <p>Account:</p>
    <%= f.fields_for :account, @account do |account| %>
      <%= account.label :city %>
      <%= account.text_field :city, id: 'city_field' %>

      <%= account.label :email %>
      <%= account.text_field :email, id: 'email_field' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee**

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  status = $("#status_select")
  city = $("#city_field")

  city.on "change", ->
    alert "city field changed!"

  status.on "change", ->
    alert "status field changed!"
```

I can get every other fields like city for example here but can't get the  select field. I only seems to be able to get it from his class like this `status = $("select")` but in the future I'll have multiple selectors in this page and I need access to this one in specific.

I don't understand what make this selector field different from the text_fields and why I can't simply give him an id or name and access it.

Comment: Have you had a look at the console in your web browser? Sometimes it can give errors telling you what's wrong. I'm kind of guessing here but it looks like your id: 'status_select' is still within the options_for_select parenthesis. Try moving it outside of these and see if it works.

Comment: No error in my web console. Also `id: 'status_select'` was originally outside the options_for_select and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the resulting html elements that are generated have the ids you expect. It looks like you are adding the id 'status_select' to each of the select options instead of the select element itself. Try:

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(%w(Visitor Member), selected: user.status), {}, {id: 'status_select'} %>
```